# Using Multi Binding in telerik Datagrid

Tags: wpf, data-binding, telerik, mvvm-light, telerik-grid

How do I pass multiple parameters in command parameters.

here is what I am trying to do:
 I want to send Is checked or not (I can do this by introducing a Boolean field to the object bound. But I dont want to do that) and I want to send the selected data object for that row.

```
                <telerik:GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <CheckBox Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type telerik:GridViewDataControl}}, Path=DataContext.LineItemSelection}">
                            <CheckBox.CommandParameter>
                                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource CommandConverter}">
                                    <Binding Path="IsChecked" />
                                    <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"/>
                                </MultiBinding>
                            </CheckBox.CommandParameter>
                        </CheckBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </telerik:GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
```

**UPDATE:**

I added a class called selection Item. To see what the converter is getting.

```
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        SelectionItem si = new SelectionItem();
        foreach (var value in values)
        {
            Type t = value.GetType();
            if (t.FullName == "System.Boolean")
                si.IsSelected = (bool) value;
            else
            {
                si.SelectedCustomer = value as Customer;
            }
        }
        return si;
    }
```

The type of the second parameter is the checkbox itself if I use

```
    <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"/>
```

Here I want the data item that is bound to that row(in this case Customer). 
I even tried using

```
    <Binding RelativeSource= "{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type telerik:GridViewColumn}}" Path="DataContext"  />
```

But this is also coming in as null. why is this?

Answer (score 0):

Try out simple binding by passing in converter current binding source, then cast to underlying object and based on IsChecked return a value.

```
<DataTemplate>
      <CheckBox Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type telerik:GridViewDataControl}}, Path=DataContext.LineItemSelection}">
         <CheckBox.CommandParameter>
               <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource CommandConverter}">
                     <Binding Path="IsChecked" />
                     <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"/>
                </MultiBinding>
         </CheckBox.CommandParameter>
       </CheckBox>
</DataTemplate>
```

```cs
 // CommandConverter should simply return the values
 public object Convert(...)
 {
     return values;
 }
```

Now in command handler you would be able access parameters:

```
public void OnLineItemSelection(object parameter)
{
    object[] parameters = (object[])parameter;
    bool isChecked = (double)parameters[0];
    var instance = (TYPENAME)parameters[1];
}
```

Comment: I did this and debugged it. both the parameters are coming in as null.

Comment: I added a class called selection Item. To see what the converter is getting.

Comment: Try out uisng  `<Binding Path="."/>` instead of ` <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"/>`

Comment: Or simply `<Binding />` hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

using

```
<CheckBox Name="chkSelection" Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type telerik:GridViewDataControl}}, Path=DataContext.LineItemSelection}">
    <CheckBox.CommandParameter>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource CommandConverter}">
            <Binding Path="IsChecked" ElementName="chkSelection" />
            <Binding />
        </MultiBinding>
    </CheckBox.CommandParameter>
</CheckBox>
```

did the trick

Comment: I tried to add this to the question it self. But was not able to see the code(probably a formatting error from my side). that is why I added the answer here.